# Filtering data in another sheet and changing data in the original

Tags: google-sheets

I have a lot of data that I need to filter. I did it in another sheet, and that's good, but now I need to put some values in that sheet and transfer that data to the original. This is the formula I'm using:

`=FILTER( Responses!A2:E300 ;  Responses!D2:D300=B1)`

Data will be in Colummn F.

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 1):

In the original sheet you can use the `INDEX` function to extract a value from the filtered sheet:

`=INDEX(reference, row, column, range)`

So, to give an example:

`=INDEX(SORT!B:B, 200, 1)`

The `INDEX` function may not be part of the `FILTER` function, otherwise you get a circular reference error.